# PBC: get hash from an element

Tags: c, hash, cryptography

In the PBC library there is a function to get an element from a hash:

> `void element_from_hash(element_t e, void *data, int len)`
>
> Generate an element e deterministically from the len bytes stored in the buffer data.

[PBC manuals: Converting elements](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/ch04s03.html)

Is there a way to go the other way around, i.e. recover the corresponding hash from an element?
Alternatively, is there a consistent way to translate strings back and forth to elements?
Does `element_to_bytes` / `element_from_bytes` work or do these bytes be ina particular form to be interpreted as a PBC element (as I strongly suppose)?

I am building a cryptosystem and clearly I need to recover the cleartext after the decryption ;).
To explain better my problem, I need a way to encode strings as an element and decode an element to a string.

Comment: There should be both functions available (I haven't looked closely) to get a hashed element from some data and to get a hash of bytes from an element. Generally, you only need one of them and not both (because they are not reversable). Keep in mind that hybrid encryption or rather key encapsulation method only requires one of those functions for both encryption and decryption, so you should think hard about your crypto system or ask a question on [crypto.se].

Comment: @ArtjomB. No, I need to translate a message into an element, like in RSA you have to encode your message into an integer.

Comment: You don't have to encode a message to an integer for RSA encryption or decryption. Have a look at [Key Encapsulation Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation). This is basically how *all* encryption works that uses elliptic curves.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I get your point that I could simply generate a random element as a 'message' and use it to derive a symmetric key, I was aware of that and in fact my backup plan was to use `element_to_bytes` and then hash.
I wandered if there was such a function both for testing purposes and because it would be an embedded KDF of some sorts (again nice to have for testing).

Answer (score 0):

I studied the manual and looked up some theory. I am not an expert in cryptography and forgot much about eliptic rings and groups.

The basic purpose of Pairing-Based Cryptography is to be able to safely exchange or construct a shared key for use in further encryption or authentication, knowing that someone may be eavesdropping on the communications used in the exchange/construction.

The hashing the manual and theory talks about means to generate a hash from the message. That hash will in turn be used to obtain a component of a key from the ring using the functions of the PBC library.

Hashing *by definition* means to map from something larger onto something smaller. For example generating a 16 bit integer hash from a 1024 character message. As a consequence it is also by definition **not** possible to obtain an original from a hash - there are an infinite number of messages that would qualify as they all generate the same hash.

However, using the key obtained from the exchange and using the library's functions lets you decrypt the message.

Comment: You may have misunderstood my question, I do not have to hash, but convert a string into an element and viceversa. I mentioned the hash because there is the function element_from_hash that lets me encode a string just like I want, not because I am working with hashes.

Comment: To my understanding, the element from `element_from_hash` is a much smaller thing than a message. The function does not encrypt but identifies a [component of a] key that can be used to encrypr/decrypt. So the scheme is: 1) get key; 2) encrypt message with key; 3) send message; 4) identify key for/from message; 5) decrypt. `element_from_hash` is used in step 4 (if I understad the theory correctly)

Comment: I am not using the function to encrypt but to encode, then I will proceed to encrypt. Namely everyone should be able to encode and decode, it is just a mean to translate the message into an algebraic structure that I will exploit to encrypt.
Moreover keep in mind that there are a lot of encryption schemes that work very differently, and PBC is a 'general purpose' library, not specific for a scheme. I may concede that `element_from_hash` seems to have been conceived for digital signature algorithms, but nothing says that it might be used otherwise.